# hide or remove review stars single product page

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, review

I am very new to tech and have the mental capacity of a fish. I have a wordpress site using woocommerce, astra theme and elementor where on my single product page two sets of stars are showing in the review section usually there should be five but in this case there are ten. [duplicate review stars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPfOV.png)

I have created a child theme to make changes to my sites .css and functions.php files without directly editing files however i am stumped on figuring out a solution,  i have never written a line of code as of yet so if someone could spell it out to me how i can get rid of this glitch i would be very grateful.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We can't "debug" mere screenshots here. _"how i can get rid of this glitch"_ - by properly investigating what _caused_ it in the first place. If you get two `<p class="stars">` elements here instead of one, then that is probably due to some plugin binding itself to a hook/filter twice.

Comment: This is my first post so apologies for the format

Answer (score 1):

```css
p.stars:nth-child(2){
   display:none;
}
```

should remove second stars field